# Retrofit2: wait for response before executing next task in recyclerview

Tags: android-recyclerview, retrofit

I am using recyclerview to display list of items(image and text), i am fetching the items displayed in the recyclerview list from backend, i am using retrofit2 for making rest calls and i am able to get the list from the rest and recyclerview is rendered perfectly fine.

while displaying the list of items in the recyclerview i want to add a bitmap image to the image present in the item. Before adding this bitmap image to the image present in the item, i have to make a second retrofit call(async) to checking whether bitmap image is need for that item, if the response is true then only i have to add the bitmap image.

Now the issue is, as i am making asynchronous call(using enqueue method) in retrofit, the recycler view is not waiting for the response from retrofit because of which am not able to draw the bitmap on the image present in the each item.

I know we can use synchronous call fix the issue but i dont want to compromise on the performance.

Below are the code snippets for reference.

I am call retrofit method from the recyclerview adapter which will return boolean based on the returned value i want to draw the bitmap on the item image

Retrofit method:

```
HttpRestServiceConsumer.getBaseApiInterface(false)
    .getTestWithURL(imageURL)
    .enqueue(new Callback<TestResponse>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<TestResponse> call, Response<TestResponse> response) {

            try {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    data = response.body().getTrackElements();

                    if (response.body().getTrackElements().size() > 0) 

                          testExist = true;

                   else 

                    testExist=false;


            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<TestResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to get the test for existence to register in the calling class. *One* way to do this is to declare an interface...

```
public interface GetTestWithURLCompletion {
    public void getTestWithURLCompletion(boolean success);
}
```

Your calling class should adopt this interface...

```
public class CustomClass implements GetTestWithURLCompletion  {

   public void getTestWithURLCompletion(boolean success) {
         if (success) // do something
   }
}
```

and the URL function should accept the caller as a parameter:

```
    public void getTestWithURL(String imageURL, GetVeepWithURLCallback caller);
```

The calling class sends a reference to itself as part of the call to getTestWithURL:

```
    webServiceManager.getTestWithURL(imageURL, this);
```

Then `getTestWithURL` can call back to invoke the interface in the calling class:

```
 caller.getTestWithURLCompletion(testExist);
```

The full example would look like this:

```
//interface
public interface GetTestWithURLCompletion {
    public void getTestWithURLCompletion(boolean success);
}

//api access class
public class ApiManager {

    //getTestWithURL
    public void getTestWithURL(String imageURL, GetVeepWithURLCallback caller) {

    HttpRestServiceConsumer.getBaseApiInterface(false)
    .getTestWithURL(imageURL)
    .enqueue(new Callback<TestResponse>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<TestResponse> call, Response<TestResponse> response) {

            try {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    data = response.body().getTrackElements();

                    if (response.body().getTrackElements().size() > 0) {
                      caller.getTestWithURLCallback(true);
                    } else {
                      caller. getTestWithURLCallback(false);
                   }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<TestResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        }
   }
}


//calling class
public class CustomClass implements GetTestWithURLCompletion  {

   //calling function
   public void someFunction {
       apiManager.getTestWithURL(imageURL, this)
  }

   //callback function
   public void getTestWithURLCompletion(boolean success) {
         if (success) // do something
   }
}
```

Experts in Java (I am not one of them) might be able to enhance this answer with examples using anonymous functions or lambda expressions. Passing an anonymous function to getTestWithUrl would save having to provide a separate callback function and could make this pattern more portable. It might look something like...

```
apiManager.getTestWithUURL(imageURL,(boolean success) -> {
             if (success) // do something
})
```

(this syntax is definitely wrong - treat as pseudocode!)